# Beginner: how to model net change given an incomplete set of input/output figures

Tags: regression

this is my first post on the Stack Exchange site, and I'm looking for some guidance.

I have a set of 10x input numbers (positive), and a set of 10x output numbers (negative), as well as the real net change.

In a perfect world, adding those twenty numbers up would be equal to the 'real net change'. Unfortunately, the set in incomplete, and every week there is an error. If it's of any help, the error is always in the same direction (modelled change too big) - it appears that the set of output numbers is incomplete. Sometimes though, the error is non-existent.

What approach would you recommend to model the real change?

I used Weka for regression analysis, but it appears to me that weka is much more powerful when used with categorising problems rather than continuous data.

I appreciate all comments and apologise if the problem stated is too general.